# Repeating code in an if qualifier in Stata

Tags: stata

In Stata I  am trying to repeat code inside an `if` qualifier using perhaps a `forvalues` loop. My code looks something like this:

```
gen y=0

replace y=1 if x_1==1 & x_2==1 & x_3==1 & x_4==1
```

Instead of writing the `& x_i==1` statement every time for each variable, I want to do it using a loop, something like this:

```
gen y=0

replace y=1 if forvalues i=1/4{x_`i'==1 &}
```

LATER EDIT:

Would it be possible to create a local in the line of this with the elements added together:

```
forvalues i=1/4{

    local text_`i' "x_`i'==1 &"

    display "`text_`i''"
    }
```

And then call it at the if qualifier ?

Answer (score 1):

Although you use the term "`if` statement" all your code is phrased in terms of `if` qualifiers, which aren't commands or statements. (Your use of the term "statement" is looser than customary, but that doesn't affect an answer directly.)

You can't insert loops in `if` qualifiers.

See for the differences

```
help if 
help ifcmd
```

The entire example

```
gen y = 0
replace y = 1 if x==1 | x==2 | x==3 | x==4
```

would be better as

```
gen y = inlist(x, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

or (dependent possibly on whatever values are allowed)

```
gen y = inrange(x, 1, 4)
```

A loop solution could be

```
gen y = 0 

quietly forval i = 1/4 { 
    replace y = 1 if x == `i' 
}
```

We can't discuss whether `inlist()` or `inrange()` would or would not be a solution for your real problem if you don't show to us.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your answer. I made a comment in the question about the forval solution.

Comment: The extra idea in the edit to the question is a start on a solution that writes code to write code. That is sometimes a good idea, but it seems pointless complexity for the example you give,

Comment: Good point. I have tried to update the example with some code, that better fits the problem.

Comment: You're not changing my view.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for taking your time. I just find it time consuming, if I for instance have 30 x_i's variables and then I have to write 30, "& x_i==1" statements.

Comment: I doubt that you do. There will be other ways to solve a more complicated version of the problem. You just need to tell us what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't like - in Nick's terms - to write code to write code. I see an immediate, though not elegant nor 'heterodox', solution to your issue. The whole thing amounts to generate an indicator function for all your indicators, and use it with your if qualifier.

Implicit assumptions, which make this a bad, non-generalizable solution, are: 1) all variables are dummies, and you need them to be == 1, and 2) variable names are conveniently ordered 1 to N (although, if that is not the case, you can easily change the forv into a 'foreach var of varlist etc.')

`g touse = 1`

`forv i =1/30{`

```
  replace touse = touse * x_'i'
```

`}`

`<your action> if touse == 1`